# R - formating list of variables as date in the same data frame

Tags: r, format, lapply, as.date

I have 50 variables named `Date1 - Date50` stored in `data1` (among other variables).

The initial format of `Date1 - Date50` is "`factor`".
The values are like "`24.01.2014`".

How can I format all 50 variables as a Date at once?

For a single variable the following command works fine:

```
data1$Date1<-as.Date("data1$Date1", format="%d.%m.%Y")
```

I tried several ways with "lapply" but without success.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `data1[] <- lapply(data1, function(x) as.Date(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))`  asssuming that you have a 50 column dataset and all the columns you want to change to 'Date' class.

Comment: I get a error message.Remember "data1" has also several other variables. If I has only the date1-date50 columns it would probably work.

Comment: In that case, you need to subset the 'Date' columns alone.  I didn't read that you have different other columns.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it for you.

```
data1[, paste0("Date", 1:50)] <- 
  lapply(data1[, paste0("Date", 1:50)],
         function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
```